# React + Webpack bundle img tags

Tags: webpack

I using webpack create project, and has a problem such as:

I want to used img tag import images and it is a relative route, like to

```
<img src='./images/a.jpg' />
```

but now the webpack don't to bundle images,so I'm at a loss.
the below is my code for webpack.

```
{
        test: /\.html$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [ {
          loader: 'html-loader',
          options: {
            minimize: false,
            removeComments: true,
          }
        }],
      },{
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|jpe?g)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
            {
            loader: 'url-loader',
                options: {
                    limit: 8192,
                    name:'images/[hash].[name].[ext]'
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

BTW,I don't to used require() import images, i just used relative route import images.

what to do?

Comment: Does you image exceed the size of 8192? If so, either adjust the size or better: use the `file-loader` for webpack.

Comment: I tried use the file-loader，but it still doesn't work